# python shell windows - import error

Tags: python

I'm trying to import module from local path in Python2.7.10 Shell on Windows

I add local path to `sys.path` by:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\download')
```

next I try to import by:

```
from download.program01 import *
```

but I've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from download.program01 import *
ImportError: No module named download.program01
```

On Linux this code works fine.

Does someone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `download` is in your pythonpath, then you should import `program01` directly.

Also, please don't import *; it makes things very hard to debug. Just do `import program01`.

Answer (score 0):

put a file `__init__.py` in your download folder so that python knows it is a module and do `sys.path.append('C:')` instead. 
If you want to keep just using path and not create a module file (the `__init___.py`) then just keep your code like that but import doing

```
import program01
```